# Is there jQuery Mobile's equivalent to the Android's ViewPager?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create a horizontal swiping effect using jQuery Mobile. After doing a little bit of research, I found out that [`ViewPager`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html), which is generally found in the app details page of Android Market, does what I want. In the page specified the author describes it along with code in Android, but I wanted to know if there is an equivalent plug-in or feature in jQM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [SwipeJS](http://swipejs.com/), it's lightweight and I like the one-to-one slide factor it uses (when you slide your finger across the element, it moves at the same rate).

There is also [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) that works pretty well (it seems to be more difficult to setup than SwipeJS).

You can however utilize the built-in `swipe` events in jQuery Mobile. You can bind to the `swipeleft` or `swiperight` events for the `data-role="page"` element(s) and navigate the user to the correct page based on the current page:

```
$(document).delegate('#page-two', 'swipeleft', function () {
    //next page
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page-three'));
}).delegate('#page-two', 'swiperight', function () {
    //prev page
    $.mobile.changePage($('#page-one'), { reverse : true });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fFGvD/

Notice the `{ reverse : true }` object being passed as the option object to the `changePage()` function so the animation will play in reverse.