# How to make Firefox-os ViewPager like Android?

Tags: android-viewpager, firefox-os

How to implement UI pattern like [Android ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), is it possible? I'm android developer and totally newbie for firefox-os and web-programming.

Comment: It is probably better to look for HTML5 implementations that are like `ViewPager`. Firefox OS uses web technologies, after all. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076329/is-there-jquery-mobiles-equivalent-to-the-androids-viewpager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though Firefox OS build on web technology and we develop app with this technology (html5, javascript). So like android viewpager here is lots of jquery slider plugin. You can use any of them. jquery mobile can help you for better UI Click [here](http://jquerymobile.com/)